# На сколько ты хочешь к нам прийти?

Tags: грамотная-речь, стилистика, стилистическая-ошибка

Задумался, а насколько правильно по-русски говорить: "На сколько ты хочешь к нам прийти?". Не будет ли это считаться ошибкой?
Может быть, правильно будет сказать: "Как долго вы хотите у нас пробыть?"

Comment: "На сколько" ещё может означать "во сколько". И этот вариант выходит на первый план.

Comment: @oleedd  Как "на сколько" может означать "во сколько"?

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец Может, связано с этим: *На какое время вам назначено?* => *На сколько вам назначено?* => *На [во] сколько ты придёшь?* Такое часто можно услышать, может не во всех регионах.

Comment: @oleedd  Да уж – не приходилось слышать.

Comment: Действительно, как "настолько" может означать "во сколько"? Приведенный вами вариант — просторечие. Вполне грамотно: во сколько вам назначено.

Comment: @Серж Серьёзно? В Гугл статистику посмотрите. Ваш вариант означает, во сколько сказали, когда прийти.

Comment: Да, верно. Ну вы же сами же пишете: "насколько" означает "во сколько".

Comment: @Серж Но при "назначено" не заменяется, так как "назначить на" и "назначить в" имеют разный смысл. И "на" отдельно пишется.

Answer (score 1):

Вопросы со словом "сколько" нужно аккуратно использовать во временном контексте. Например, не верно говорить "сколько времени" или "во сколько", потому что "сколько" - это временной промежуток(интервал), а не точное время, так что правильно было бы говорить "который час/в котором часу".
Здесь же происходит другое, глагол "прийти" про перемещение в пространстве, а не про время, поэтому возникает диссонанс, да и сама фраза "прийти во сколько" некорректна(почему-написано выше). А вот "сколько хотите пробыть" - уместно, потому что "быть" связано с временным промежутком "сколько". Ну и если уже дальше занудствовать, то "сколько" в русском связано скорее с однотипным измерением: сколько монет, сколько ударов(мятника). Замена же "сколько" на "как долго" убирает все противоречия, потому что "долго" - именно про временной промежуток, а не про счётные материальные объекты или однотипные события.

Так что лучше в связке со временем использовать слова "когда, как долго" и тд, а не "сколько". Тогда диссонанса возникать не будет.

Comment: А что насчет "На сколько вы бы хотели получить визу?"? Оно тоже некорректно? Стоит ли перефразировать как "Визу с каким сроком действия вы бы хотели получить?"?

Comment: "На какой срок вы хотели бы(планируете) получить(оформить) визу?" Из закона "...обыкновенная частная виза выдается на срок до одного года иностранному гражданину" - то есть присутствует выражение виза, выданная 'на срок до', поэтому вопрос лучше задавать к слову срок, а не к слову виза, как мне кажется.

Comment: Виза - слово указывающее на общий вид документа, ничего не говорящее о внутренней опциональности этого документа. Если вопрос касается именно качества визы, то речь может идти о том рабочая это виза или туристическая, а сроки действия виз устанавливаются уже в частном порядке - это уже "опции". "Могла попросить визу на год, а не на пол..."  "На сколько вы бы хотели получить визу" - говорить можно, но это, скорее, разговорная форма. Понять, скорее всего, вас поймут, но кому-то может резать слух. "Визу с каким сроком действия вы бы хотели получить?" - тоже можно, но на мой слух, тяжеловесно.